# Not able to revert back to tensorflow 1.5.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am try to install

`pip install tensorflow==1.5.0`

and I am getting this error:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.6.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5.0
```

Comment: What version of pip and python are you using? Tensorflow has specific [system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a virtual env with python 3.6 (supports tensorflow 1.5) and install tensorflow. You probably have  a newer version of python installed (e.g.- python 3.8 supports tensorflow 2.2 or later and python 3.9 supports tensorflow 2.5 or later).

In the terminal:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
pip install tensorflow==1.5.0
```

Comment: yes I have newer versions as you mentioned....checking with virtual env